# Would it make sense to use the "plus" and "minus" components of \baselineskip?

Tags: typography, lengths, vertical-spacing

According to [latexref.xyz](https://latexref.xyz/_005cbaselineskip-_0026-_005cbaselinestretch.html):

> The `\baselineskip` is a rubber length

but also

> The `\baselineskip`’s value is reset every time a font change happens and so any direct change to `\baselineskip` would vanish the next time there was a font switch.

Now if I do `\showthe\baselineskip` in an empty `article` I see `12.0pt`, without `plus` and `minus` component. Would it make sense to use these components? In what situations, and how does one use these components if the value gets reset? If it does not make sense, why is it specifically a *rubber* length?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost never want variable baseline spacing in normal running text, but it can be useful in some display contexts, eg to adjust the line spacing to make a paragraph match the height of an adjacent image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\includegraphics[height=6cm, width=3cm]{example-image}
\parbox[b][6cm][b]{3cm}{%
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[height=6cm, width=3cm]{example-image}
\parbox[b][6cm][s]{3cm}{%
\setlength\baselineskip{12pt plus 5pt minus 1pt}
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
A paragraph of text alongside an image.
}


\end{document}
```